# computational considerations on the regression problems

Tags: regression, computational-statistics

I am reading Elements of Statistical Learning and read the following claim from the text (page 93, Chapter 3.7):

Least squares fitting is usually done via the Cholesky decomposition of the matrix $\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}$ or a QR Decomposition of $\mathbf{X}$. With $N$ obserations and $p$ features, the Cholesky decomposition requires $p^3 + Np^2/2$ operations, while the QR decomposition requires $Np^2$ operations.

I understand Cholesky and QR decompositions individually, but I do not understand where this claim came from. Please help.

Comment: The results look very very simply, since they are of polynomial form. But I really am stumped as to where these originate.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should just trust the book unless you're really interested.

Nevertheless, this, plus plenty more to help you understand numerical considerations for least squares, is covered in [G.W. Stewart 'Matrix Algorithms: Volume 1: Basic Decompositions'](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971408). Chapters 3 and 4 respectively for Cholesky and QR.  All that you wanted to know, a lot that you didn't even realize you want to know, and some you probably would be just as happy not knowing.